# Proving a function in $\operatorname{GF}(2^n)$ is differentially k-uniform

Tags: finite-field

I want to show that $F(x) = x^{-1}$ in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{n})$  is differentially 4-uniform for even $n$, and is differentially 2-uniform for odd $n$, without looking at the Differential Distribution Table.

My attempt:

Let $\alpha, \beta \in \operatorname{GF}(2^{n})$ and $\alpha \neq 0$

$$(x+\alpha)^{-1} - x^{-1} = \beta$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x + \alpha} - \frac{1}{x} = \beta$$

$$\Rightarrow \beta x^{2}+ \alpha \beta x + \alpha = 0$$

How can we show the equation has at most 4 or 2 solutions in $\operatorname{GF}(2^{n})$?

Comment: It's a polynomial in one variable over a field. You should know of a result that bounds the number of solutions.

Comment: It has at most 4 solutions, i think we don't need the bound.

Comment: It has at most 2 solutions; as Daniel said, in a field, a nontrivial quadratic over a single variable has at most 2 solutions, and that's a quite well known result.

Comment: For reference: $F$ being $k$-uniform is defined as meaning: $k$ is the maximum number of solutions $x$ to $F(x+\alpha)+F(x)=\beta$ when $\alpha\ne0$ and $\beta$ take all possible pairs of values. Note: I guess the definition of this question's $F$ assumes $F(0)=0$. Hint: do the algebra carefully. $u=v\mathrel{\mathord{\rlap{\hspace{.55em}\not}}\mathord{\Longleftrightarrow}}u\,w=v\,w$.